# For- loop which can reuse updated values

Tags: procedural-programming, iterators

```
Eout = E^x ;
For[kz = 1, kz < 4, kz++, 
  Print[Eout1[kz] = Eout];
  Print[kz]]
```

The output is

> ```
> E^x
> 1
> E^x
> 2
> E^x
> 3
> ```

But what I want to have is

> ```
> E^x
> 1
> E^x.E^x
> 2
> E^x.E^x.E^x
> 3
> ```

Is it possible to get the desired output by using `Table` or a loop with `Do` or `While`?

Comment: Your question needs more from your side. Please explain better what you have and what you need. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share minimal working code in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) accordingly. Also, **please take the [tour]**, it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) it will inspire great answers.

Comment: Have you seen the Mathematica function called [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)? Also [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) Would that solve your problem?
Try `NestList[Times[Exp[x], #] &, E0, 5]`

Comment: [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) and [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) could also be of interest here, in case the second argument $e^x$ changes from one step to the next. Because multiplying repeatedly by the same factor can be abbreviated by a power construct: $e^x\cdot e^x=e^{2x}$ etc. very generally, even if $x$ is a matrix.

Comment: This will not work.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks! it works.

Comment: Glad it helped, just a heads up: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake and is unlikely to help any future visitors. In this case you where missing a function that is easily found in the documentation. **Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy.** Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp). And do take the [tour]!

Comment: Perhaps `data = FoldPairList[{#2, E^x #1} &, 1, {1, 2, 3}, Reverse]; Column[Flatten@data]` or simply `data = Table[{E^(k x), k}, {k, 3}]` for the first, data-generation step.